# Why changing resolution affects light intensity and focus?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am rendering same project with 100% and 200% resolutions, expecting same image with a higher resolution. As the resolution increases, light intensity seems to increase too. Also, there are other minor changes like blurred parts of the image and bump height.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a setting to keep things consistent or at least see the final render in viewport?

[image: 100% render]

[image: 200% render]

Comment: It doesn't. It probably changes the perceived size of screen space effects like glow bloom which are often specified in pixels.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos That's what I thought at first and disabled all usual suspects to confirm, but there are still differences in how much light bumps catch. See https://imgur.com/a/ewTBEuc If this is not preventable, is there a way to see how 200% resolution will look like in the viewport? So I can adjust accordingly.